# How to change color of this svg icon?

Tags: svg, colors

I have the following svg icon that I want to change the color of to #2F855A:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
    <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M8.7 14.7a1 1 0 0 1-1.4-1.4l4-4a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 0l4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.4 1.4L12 11.42l-3.3 3.3z"/>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
    <path class="heroicon-ui" fill="#2F855A" d="M8.7 14.7a1 1 0 0 1-1.4-1.4l4-4a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 0l4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.4 1.4L12 11.42l-3.3 3.3z"/>
</svg>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You need to fill the path: `fill="#2F855A"`

Comment: @lampbottle, if you want to add an answer then you have to add it as separate answer part and not into your question. Please correct it!

Answer (score 3):

```css
.icon{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
 <svg class="icon" fill="none" stroke="#2f2f2f" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path></svg>
```

You need to use `stroke` attribute on `svg`. You can choose any value you want. for example `stroke="#2f2f2f` will set the color as dark gray.